# How and where do we incorporate ASIFormDataRequest in Xcode?

Tags: php, iphone, ios, xcode, asiformdatarequest

We are attempting to modify data in iphone text-field then return (data) to mysql database in the server.

We have a few questions:

Is ASIFormDataRequest the preferred tool to use for this?  If not, could you recommend one and explain how to incorporate?
If ASIFormDataRequest is the right tool, how and where do we incorporate ASIFormDataRequest in Xcode and PHP?

Below are three files containing the code we have written and we welcome all of your insight.  Thanks for your generosities!

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
NSDictionary *newsArticle;

IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;    
IBOutlet UITextField *fieldname;
IBOutlet UITextField *fieldtitle;
IBOutlet UITextField *fielddate;}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *newsArticle;

@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize newsArticle;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

titleLabel.text = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"name"];
timeLabel.text = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"title"];


fieldname.text = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"name"];

fieldtitle.text = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"title"];

fielddate.text = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"date"];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Php file

```
$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM afitest");

$arr = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$arr[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ASIHttprequest is a framework (no, it's not a tool) that enables you to make http calls to a server application just like your browser gets a page or posts a form.

And it doesn't matter what you do with which kind of database - it neither depends on server scripting language nor on back end db: (php or mysql).

That said, there are [plenty](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=asihttprequest%20example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_rn=1&gs_ri=serp&pq=asihttprequest%20example&cp=7&gs_id=10&xhr=t&q=asiformdatarequest%20example&es_nrs=true&pf=p&client=firefox-a&hs=nqk&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&oq=asiform%20example&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bmk&fp=1ccbb6392a404df7&biw=1024&bih=677) of [examples available](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) on what ASIHttpRequest can do for you.

If you are specific or facing any problems, modify your question accordingly. You will get better help.